# ¿Cómo hacer que php tome una fecha dd/mm/AAAA como dia/mes/año, y NO mes/día/año?

Tags: php, date

Estoy intentando hacer una función que tome una fecha en formato 12/10/2022 y devuelva "miércoles 12 de octubre de 2022". Este es mi intento:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_RA.UTF-8','esp');

function funcioFecha7($fecha){
    $var = strtotime($fecha);
    $var2 = strftime('%A %d de %B de %Y', $var);
return($var2);
}

print_r(funcioFecha7('12/10/2022'));
?>
```

Pero el resultado que obtengo es " s�bado 10 de diciembre de 2022". Entiendo que hace esto porque toma 12 como mes en lugar de tomarlo como día, y viceversa. Pensé que con las configuraciones locales eso no sucedería, pero me parece que estoy mezclando conceptos. ¿Cómo podría resolverlo? Gracias!

Comment: cambia `funcioFecha7('12/10/2022')` por `funcioFecha7('12-10-2022')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En primer lugar, si vas a trabajar con fechas en PHP te aconsejo que uses [la clase **`DateTime()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), la cual te permitirá tirar ventaja de la bondad de la POO, y, quizá combinarla con otras clases para facilitar tareas realmente complejas y verbosas.

Ten en cuenta que cuando vas a crear fechas a partir de un formato, debes indicar el formato exacto en que está la fecha.

Aquí vamos a usar el método [`createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) de la clase `DateTime`. Si tu fecha `12/10/2022` representa el 12 de octubre de 2022, entonces el formato que debes aplicar al crearla es: `d/m/Y` donde:

- <kbd>**`d`**</kbd> representa el día del mes, 2 dígitos con ceros iniciales
- <kbd>**`m`**</kbd> es una representación numérica del mes, con ceros iniciales
- <kbd>**`Y`**</kbd> es una representación numérica completa de un año, 4 dígitos

[Ver aquí todos los formatos que aplican al crear fechas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php).

Luego, tienes que tener cuidado con los caracteres que separan los valores. A veces las fechas vienen con `-`, si es así, debes ponerlo en el formato, o viene sin nada, debes ponerlo así en el formato.

Entendido eso, podemos crear la fecha correctamente de este modo:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fecha);
```

Aquí `$date` será un objeto, y lo puedes usar para lo que quieras, desde algo simple como sería mostrarlo con un determinado formato, hasta algo más complicado, como calcular intervalos, períodos ... o incorporarlo al módulo `Intl` de PHP como veremos al final.

Veamos un ejemplo de tu función:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_RA.UTF-8','esp');

function funcioFecha7($fecha){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fecha);
    return $date->format("l d \\d\\e F \\d\\e Y");
}

print_r(funcioFecha7('12/10/2022'));
```

**Salida:**

```
Wednesday 12 de October de 2022
```

No uso configuraciones locales en PHP, pero he leído que, en particular para las fechas y horas, no funcionan bien, sea como sea, en muchos entornos debes tener instalado el módulo correcto para la localidad que quieres, y en ese caso es mejor usar el módulo de internacionalización de PHP.

En mi caso, los nombres salen en inglés, porque la configuración inicial no funcionó. Si tienes el local instalado en tu entorno debería funcionar, y quizá no hace falta poner esto `\\d\\e` (es para que no interprete la `d` como el formato para el día) al llamar a `format`, pudiendo ponerlo así: `return $date->format("l d F Y");`

---

#### Ejemplo con el módulo de internacionalización

Sea como sea, si vas a trabajar en serio con esto, instala el [módulo de internacionalización](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.intl.php) (si no está ya instalado en tu entorno).

Luego, tu función será tan simple como esto:

```
function spanishDate($theDate){
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $theDate, new DateTimeZone("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"));
    /*
       IntlDateFormatter::NONE es para que no muestre nada
       con respecto a la hora
    */
    $df =new IntlDateFormatter("es_RA",IntlDateFormatter::FULL,IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
    return $df->format($dt);
}
```

Prueba:

```
echo spanishDate("12/10/2022");
```

**Salida:**

```
miércoles, 12 de octubre de 2022
```

Cabe decir que la funciones de internacionalización no son sólo para fechas, sino para Calendarios, Monedas, Números, Zonas horarias, Convertidores, Normalización, etc. [como podrás ver en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.intl.php).

Answer (score 1):

El detalle de la fecha esta en como mandas la cadena como parámetro, las **/** o **-**, si cambias las diagonales por el guion te da la fecha correctamente, ejemplo:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_RA.UTF-8','esp');

function funcioFecha7($fecha){
    $var = strtotime($fecha);
    $var2 = strftime('%A %d de %B de %Y', $var);
return($var2);
}

print_r(funcioFecha7('12-10-2022'));
?>
```

> Puedes utilizar otras funciones como **str_replace** para eliminar
> caracteres especiales, dependiendo de como mandes el parámetro.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como cambiar las diagonales por guion, esto en caso de que debas enviar forzosamente el parámetro con ese formato.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_RA.UTF-8','esp');

function funcioFecha7($fecha){
    $replace = str_replace(array("/"), '-', $fecha);
    $var = strtotime($replace);
    $var2 = strftime('%A %d de %B de %Y', $var);
return($var2);
}

print_r(funcioFecha8('12/10/2022'));
?>
```

Comment: Ese formato es solo para HTML, CSS y Javascript. No es compatible con PHP.