# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el mes en español de mi pdf de codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

Mi pdf de codeigniter está mostrando el mes de una fecha que se trae de base de datos en inglés Y necesito que se vea en español. Soy nuevo trabajando en este campo pero no estoy seguro del cómo hacerlo. Por ejemplo:

Se visualiza así: 15 de August de 2023

Y requiero que se vea así: 15 de Agosto de 2023

Inserto a continuación la línea de código de mi controlador que muestra la fecha:

```
<p style="text-align: justify; color: #444444; font-weight: normal;">Conformado en <u>'.$comprobar['estados'].'</u>, al <u>'.strftime('%d de %B de %Y', strtotime($comprobar['conformacion'])).'</u>.</p>
```

Comment: Hola. Puedes crear tu propia clase para interpretar las fechas en español (ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967)) o puedes usar [la clase `IntlDateFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.intldateformatter.php) de la extensión de internacionalización si la tienes instalada en tu entorno, para más detalles ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/559451/29967).

Comment: De hecho Codeigniter viene con la clase `IntlDateFormatter` [según se puede ver aquí](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/time.html#tolocalizedstring), por lo que puedes fácilmente crear fechas localizadas.

Answer (score 1):

En codeigniter necesitas establercer esto:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.utf8', 'es_ES', 'esp');
```

*nota: se puede usar nativamente en php.*

luego:

```
// Obtener la fecha de la base de datos
$fecha_base_datos = $comprobar['conformacion'];

// Formatear la fecha en español
$fecha_formateada = strftime('%d de %B de %Y', strtotime($fecha_base_datos));
?>

<p style="text-align: justify; color: #444444; font-weight: normal;">
    Conformado en <u><?php echo $comprobar['estados']; ?></u>,
    al <u><?php echo $fecha_formateada; ?></u>.
</p>
```

con estos cambios, en la configuracion regional y la forma de formato te deberia salir como lo indicas.

Comment: Para ser precisos, la función [`setlocale()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php) no es exclusiva de CodeIgniter, es parte del núcleo de PHP.

Comment: @Sal claro deseas agregar algo mas???

Comment: Aparte de lo apuntado por @Sal, podría surgir la pregunta de si es necesario tocar la configuración local para esto. Además `setlocale` no funciona siempre ([ver esta respuesta por ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/559451/29967)) y se necesitará tener el archivo de localidad específico. Ya que [Codeigniter trae el Módulo de Internacionalización](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/time.html#tolocalizedstring), creo que es mejor resolver esto usando la clase `IntlDateFormatter`. Supongo que cuando se usa un framework es para beneficiarse de las ventajas que este ofrece.

Comment: Si tenes razon, si quieres puedes agergarlo a mi respuesta o agregar otra respuesta @A.Cedano la idea es tener la mayoria de contexto posible para diferentes escenarios.